Provisioning company's root domain as private domain
Business has a use case were financial adviser click on quick send in Salesforce CRM and that triggers API and journey in SFMC.
Currently production BU has (info.company.com) associated with SAP. Financial adviser from address is having company root domain (for example - @company.com). when they try to send email its failing and leading to spam folder. When they contact with salesforce support for this issue they have suggested to provision private domain.
Now business has purchased private domain SUK, when we started discussion with internal domain team and messaging team to provision root domain (company.com) as private domain in SFMC some internal concerns raised as security that root domain cannot be directly used for sending emails with 3rd party vendors, either we have to onboard SFMC application on Secure Email Relay (SER) an SMTP solution or file a deviation against INT9. But SFMC does not support SER and also domain team/messaging team not recommended to file deviation.
Now again business has given option to use sub-domain (email.company.com) as private domain in SFMC. In this case also the above use case may fails and emails land to spam folder. As both from address (company.com) and sub domain (email.company.com) are different.
Please suggest some solution which we need to overcome from this issue.
